# I want to clear data on whatsapp to recover my messages but i lost the number would whatsapp send a message to the umber?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

The sole reason for doing this is that I blocked and reported a contact and the contact blocked me too and I need the messages back but I don't have the old number I used to open the WhatsApp how do I get those messages back

Comment: Running WhatsApp with a phone number you don't have access to is a very bad idea. You should always migrate the account to the new number: https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/account-and-profile/about-changing-phone-numbers

Comment: I'll go a step further: "Running WhatsApp is a very bad idea."  ;)

Comment: WhatsApp will send verification code to your old number. Without thay, you can't restore chat backup.